# All java classes and objects gone (eclipse, android SDK)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've got this really weird problem, have been working on a project all night and suddenly when I open Eclipse, I get hundreds of errors.

Nothing from `String` to `Java.IO` can be found... text like `import java.io can not be resolved` is everywhere. I have no clue what I have done, anyone can give me a hint? I would really appreciate it!

/Nick

Comment: Happened to me too once. I think I solved it by reinstalling.

Comment: Sometimes the JRE Library vanishes from the Build Path, making these imports and everything fail.

Answer (score 2):

ALSO, check if your JRE is selected as the Default JRE in the Eclipse-Preferences (under Java). Common cause for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

Possible fixes:

-Reset the path to the Android SDK.

-Check if all libraries are on place

-Clear the project and try to rebuild

-Refresh the project

-Check the Console tab - sometimes the root of all problems is shown there.

-Check if there is some problems in the `res` dir, sometimes gen/R.java could't be build because of that

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me after refactoring once.
Check your .project file. Make sure it contains those entries:

```
<buildSpec>
            <buildCommand>
                    <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                    <arguments>
                    </arguments>
            </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
            <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
```